# How can I add custom name for apk?

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I use teamcity for CI and upload build with custom name to the Firebase App Distribution, but after downloading the build has default name "app.apk". How can I change it?

Comment: It would better if you also provide config file.

Comment: I can't sorry. I'm only interested in whether there is such a possibility or App Distribution always rename the build file?